# Timestamp: Las variables tienen el mismo valor al final - PHP

Tags: php, sesiones, time, timestamp

La idea es calcular los segundos que han pasado desde que se entró en la página hasta que se pulsó el botón, mediante *PHP*.

La cosa es, que quiero hacer este proceso dentro de la misma página. Anteriormente había probado enviando la petición a una página a parte, en plan, el botón en una página, y la petición que hacía ese botón con su respectivo formulario (`action`) en otra. Pasaba el *tiempo UNIX* mediante una sesión y lo restaba del actual. De esta forma sabía el tiempo que había pasado.

El problema es que al hacerlo en una misma página, al darle click al botón las variables toman el mismo valor, y el resultado siempre es `0`.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$time_ = new DateTime();

$c = $time_->getTimestamp();
echo $c;

if(isset($_POST['Palabras']) && strlen($_POST['Palabras'])>0 &&
    isset($_POST['Ordenadas']) && strlen($_POST['Ordenadas'])>0){

    $t = $time_->getTimestamp();
    echo $c - $t;
}
?>
```

Al iniciar la *página C* siempre toma *X valor*, pero al darle al *botón C* y *T* toman el último valor obtenido.

¿Cuál es la solución?

Answer (score 3):

Salvo que me equivoque, *PHP* corre del lado del servidor, por tanto cada vez que lo ejecutas, se ejecuta todo el contenido recargando la página.

Lo que quieres hacer, yo lo haría con una llamada por *AJAX* a otro fichero *PHP* que únicamente te devuelva la hora en formato *UNIX*, lo obtienes con *JavaScript*, haces el cálculo y lo muestras en pantalla. Así *no te duplicaría* los valores de las variables.

Código *JavaScript*:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'returnTime.php',

    success: function(horaActual) {
        //ahora tienes en la variable 'horaActual' el valor unix del momento actual
        //por tanto puedes reconvertirlo a formato que necesites(ddmmyy por ejemplo) y pintarlo en un div
        var diferencia = horaActual - laHoraQueYaTenias
        $('#tuDiv').html("Han pasado " + diferencia + " segundos");
    },
    error: function(respuesta) {
        $('#tuDiv').html("Hay errores. Esto es lo que devuelve php: " + respuesta);
    }
})
```

**returnTime.php**

```
echo time();
```

Todo lo que *"pintes"* con *PHP* en este archivo, irá a parar **tal cual** a la variable `horaActual` de *JavaScript*, de modo que si pusieras `"hola, son las ".time()`, o que recibiría `horaActual` es, literalmente `"hola, son las 32487623478263423"`.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta, aunque sinceramente no tengo ni la más minima idea remota de AJAX...

Comment: Hola de nuevo, primero que nada muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, pero ando algo perdido, no termino de entender de dónde AJAX saca la Hora actual, entiendo que horaactual y laHoraQueYaTenias son variables, ¿pero en que momento se les ha declarado el valor? Lamento las molestias.

Comment: Digamos que tienes tu index.php que es donde ejecutas el código php y donde se incluye al final el JS vale?
Cuando se ejecuta el AJAX, sin recargar la página, se va a ejecutar el returnTime.php de forma invisible al usuario, y el resultado de esa ejecución es lo que se asigna a horaActual.
laHoraqueYaTenias es una variable JS que tú debes haber asignado previamente con la hora digamos de carga de la página (puedes crearla directamente en JS, o puedes crearla con php, poniéndola en el "value" de un input y poniéndolo como "hidden" para que no se vea, y ese value lo capturas con JS/Jquery

Comment: ¡Vale, ahora entiendo todo! Debería empezar aprender de AJAX... Muchisimas gracias por explicarmelo y por la ayuda en general :)

Answer (score 2):

Tendrías que pasarle el time inicial al form así a la segunda vuelta tiene con que comparar

```
<?php
$time_ = new DateTime();

$c = $time_->getTimestamp();
echo $c;

      if(isset($_POST['Palabras']) && strlen($_POST['Palabras'])>0 &&
      isset($_POST['Ordenadas']) && strlen($_POST['Ordenadas'])>0){

  $c = isset($_POST['t_inicial'])?$_POST['t_inicial']:$c;


        $t = $time_->getTimestamp();
        echo $c - $t;

      }

?>
<form action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="t_inicial" value="<?php echo $c; ?>" />
```

Comment: Hola @Omar, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada si consideras que te ayudó o es la que te sirvió. Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para más información.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente no le veo sentido a querer hacer eso *del lado del servidor*, con PHP.

Si quieres calcular el tiempo transcurrido entre el inicio de la navegación en la página y el click de un botón, lo normal sería hacerlo *del lado del cliente*, usando para ello Javascript.

El procedimiento sería el siguiente:

1. Valerte de `DOMContentLoaded` para capturar el momento en que la página fue cargada (`loadDate`), o sea, el momento en que podemos decir con toda propiedad que empezó la navegación.
2. Agregar un *listener*  a tu botón, de modo que cuando se haga click en él invoque a una función dentro del contexto del DOM (`mostrarCalculo`). Esa función obtendrá una variable con el momento justo en que el botón fue pulsado (`clickDate`) y calculará la diferencia en segundos entre ese momento y la variable `loadDate` obtenida en el momento de carga de la página.

He aquí un ejemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var loadDate = new Date();
  var btn = document.getElementById("btnCalcular");
  btn.onclick = mostrarCalculo;

  function mostrarCalculo() {
    var clickDate = new Date();
    var difSeconds = (clickDate.getTime() - loadDate.getTime()) / 1000;
    console.log("Han pasado " + difSeconds + " segundos entre el inicio de la página y el click del botón");
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btnCalcular">Mostrar Cálculo</button>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Buenas, muchísimas gracias por tu comentario, lo plantée en PHP porque si el tiempo excedía de 5 segundos la consulta no se mandaría a la base de datos. (Tengo muy muy poca idea sobre Javascript) por ello buscaba alternativas mediante PHP. Supongo que debería empezar a aprender de lenguajes del lado del cliente y dejar de pretender hacer todo por lado de servidor. ¿Hay alguna forma de mandar/no mandar la petición si excedió de esos 5 segundos? Y por último y más importante, ¿es posible editar el tiempo desde el inspector de elementos? ¿Podría una persona trucar el script para tener más tiempo?

Comment: Las páginas web modernas son una combinación de PHP/HTML/Javascript. Con esa combinación puedes escribir cualquier cosa, aquí la clave es que *cada cosa tiene que ocurrir del lado adecuado*. En este caso, todo el cálculo entre que se ingresó a la página y se hizo click en el botón, tendría que ocurrir *del lado del cliente*, porque es el cliente el que accede a la página, por más que tú intentes de calcularlo del lado del servidor, serán cálculos irreales y además cargas al servidor de forma innecesaria. En cuanto a tu otra pregunta, desde ese mismo código Javascript tú puedes calcular ...

Comment: ... si el tiempo transcurrido es o no mayor a 5 segundos y actuar en consecuencia. Cuando sea necesario enviar una petición cualquiera al servidor, entonces ahí entraría otro componente muy potente del cual no puede prescindir ninguna página web moderna: **Ajax**. Podemos decir que es parte de Javascript y funciona del lado del cliente, es como un puente entre el cliente y el servidor. Entonces por medio de él enviarías la petición al servidor si procediere. Ajax te permite por ejemplo recoger datos de la página actual y pasarla al servidor para que trabaje con esos datos. @SharkiAragon

Comment: Entiendo, supongo que va siendo hora de mirar como funciona AJAX, (y javascript en general), hace tiempo quise aprender Ajax, pero vi que era tan diferente a los lenguajes de programación a los que estaba acostumbrado que terminé echandome para atras. En fin, muchíiiiisimas gracias por tu tiempo, y por toda la información transmitida, de verdad, muchas gracias!! :)

Comment: @SharkiAragon Realmente Ajax no es tan raro, pues es código Javascript. Lo que pasa es que Ajax se suele usar con jQuery (que es una librería de Javascript)... y es él, jQuery, el que es raro :)  pero todo es cuestión de acostumbrarse y cuando has aprendido lo fundamental, todo va sobre ruedas, ya que la combinación PHP/HTML/Javascript/Ajax te permiten hacer cualquier tipo de operación con suma facilidad, y cada cosa del lado que le corresponde. A mi también Ajax me sonaba a chino al principio, pero ya no tanto, porque vas aprendiendo con el tiempo y con la práctica. Saludos.